# How do I get the error line number in my Android application?

Tags: android, debugging

Currently when my application has an error I get a stack trace that I don't recognize at all (doesn't contain any of the classes I defined), so debugging requires always adding at least 1 break point to then trace execution through my code.

How can I set up Eclipse so that when an error happens I get the line number in my actual application that caused the error? (thereby giving me a better chance of fixing right away without going through additional debug steps)

Copied below is the stack trace that I don't recgonize. I tried pausing the other threads in case my code was somewhere in there, but it's nowhere to be found.

```
GoogleImageSearch [Android Application] 
DalvikVM[localhost:8606]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended)   
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(int, int) line: 2135    
        ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(View, WindowManager$LayoutParams, Resources, int, int) line: 1286 
        ViewRootImpl.performTraversals() line: 1497 
        ViewRootImpl.doTraversal() line: 1183   
        ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run() line: 4863 
        Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(long) line: 749    
        Choreographer.doCallbacks(int, long) line: 562  
        Choreographer.doFrame(long, int) line: 532  
        Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run() line: 735 
        Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 725   
        Choreographer$FrameHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92   
        Looper.loop() line: 137 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5328    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1102 
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 869 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Suspended)  
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        NativeStart.run() line: not available [native method]   
    Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Suspended)   
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        NativeStart.run() line: not available [native method]
```

**Edit**: To address the possibility that it's something unique to my application that was causing my sources to be missing from the stack trace, I created a HelloWorld application using Eclipse's New Android Application wizard. It ran fine with a blank screen. Then I added one line to `MainActivity`'s `onCreate`: `long l = 100 / 0`. I then got this (note that MainActivity.java does not appear anywhere in the stack, which makes me wonder what value showing the stack information provides at all. There must be a way to customize this.)

```
HelloWorld [Android Application]    
DalvikVM[localhost:8611]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2247    
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2297 
        ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 152    
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1282  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 137 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5328    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1102 
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 869 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Suspended)  
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        NativeStart.run() line: not available [native method]   
    Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Suspended)   
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        NativeStart.run() line: not available [native method]
```

**FINAL_EDIT**: This question is based on a erroneous assumption about the debuggers ability to detect errors and suspend threads accordingly. It may suspend the thread way before LogCat has been used to report on any errors. LogCat may have worked just fine in all my previous cases listed above if I'd just continued resuming threads until the application terminates with an error.

Comment: The full stack trace (what you have shown here) will always show all classes/methods that are on the stack when the exception occured. Since none of your classes are in the stack trace, there is no `line number in my actual application that caused the error`. Consider searching for posts online where people have come across a similar issue, and if their solutions work for you. My guess is it has something to do with your resources or layouts.

Comment: @Yjay I don't see the logic in your reasoning - it there is no line number in my application that caused the error, then how is it possible to ever fix the error if I only control the lines of code in my source code? The example I showed is definitely attributable to a single line in my source code because it was introduced by changes I made in my source code.

Comment: How are you getting this stack trace?  It does not look like LogCat output.  I have never seen a trace in LogCat that did not include application-level code (with a line number.)

Comment: This is a copy-paste from the process "tree"* Eclipse's Debug view. (*Tree might not be the right word - it's a structure with root node being my application name, and a port number used for debugging, with current threads as children)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find the error line when looking in the LogCat window in eclipse, the error that appears should show a line saying 'Caused at..' And the next couple of lines should identify the line that causes the error (line number should be at the end of the error line)

If you don't see the LogCat window enable it by Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android-> Logcat

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused because the error occurred in an Activity's `onCreate` method. By observation (I have no documentation to back up this statement) it seems that methods that are run as part of an application's "bootstrap" process are handled differently to errors that occur during the "normal" lifetime of an application.

I solved this by taking the code out of `onCreate` and adding it to another method which I call by clicking on a dummy button I added to the layout. Once I've debugged the code I will put it back in `onCreate`.

I longer term solution for this case is definitely needed for Android.

**EDIT**: And the error also started appearing in LogCat, which it hadn't been available in previously.

**ANOTHER_EDIT**: I've also since discovered cases where the technique in this solution doesn't work (back to same problem of application failing with no output in LogCat for log messages for my application). These cases would make my solution incomplete, so I won't mark it as an answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

LogCat is a reliable way of getting the line number that causes errors in an Android application. One reason for it not reporting an error can be that the debugger suspends one or many threads affected by an exception before LogCat has been called to report an unhandled exception. In this case you have a suspended thread displaying the exception type, yet with no output from LogCat.

If you run the application using the debugger then just make sure to resume threads until the application terminates with a fatal error, which is when you'll get the LogCat output. It may take multiple un-suspends to get it to a point where you get the LogCat message.

But that technique begs the question - why use the debugger at all if on suspension of a thread you aren't taken to the code source that caused the error?

The solution I've gone with is just to run my application without the debugger as much as possible.